# SP 2010 Infrastrucure - looking at options for 2010 around dev and also ntlm vs kerberos (in general)

Tags: kerberos

I am trying to get an idea of infrastructure layouts that others are using.  In our current 2007 environment we have 3 farms:

Dev
Model
Prod

All VMs
2500 users
between 100 and 150GB total content
less than 5 devs at this time, hoping to attrack more use from other development groups

We are migrating to 2010 in the next few months and I am reassessing.  I have spoken with some admins who have suggested individual VMs for each developer as needed.  The devs test on their VMs and promote to Model and on to Production.

Do any of you use this method?  If not, what is the general setup in your organization?

NTLM vs Kerberos?
Also, looking for any opinions on ntlm vs kerberos for LAN only environment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alex that your dev process is commonly used and is fine.

A lot of people come across the double hop problem when using BI within SharePoint. If your organization is likely to use BI at some stage then I would suggest doing Kerberos up front - it shouldn't require much extra work and if you aren't using SharePoint for BI then why not? - It's great! ;-)

The extra work required to get Kerberos working should be minimal and for the small amount of extra effort I would recommend installing Kerberos by default.

Answer (score 0):

Dev process seems to be fine. Many people do it that way. You might want to have a look at the new TFS<->SharePoint integration and its automations feaures.

NTLM vs. Kerberos: You are fine with NTML as long you dont come to the "double hop" problem. You can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knowledgecast/the-double-hop-problem).